# How to pass value from a button in table into another view in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How could I pass a model's value from a view into another view when a link button is pressed?

**CONTROLLER:**

```
public class ViewModel
    {

        public List<DeliverySchedule> ScheduleList { get; set; } 

        public DeliverySchedule ScheduleDetail { get; set; }
    }

public class DeliverySchedule
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string split_date { get; set; }
    public string split_hour { get; set; }
    public string split_qty { get; set; }
    public string remarks { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    var model = new ViewModel();

    model.ScheduleDetail = sipContext.OrderDeliverySchedules
                        .Where(o => o.Id == id).SingleOrDefault();                  

    return View(model);
}
```

**VIEW:**

```
@model Interisland.Areas.v2.Controllers.OrderConfirmationController.ViewModel
@{
    var ScheduleList = Model.ScheduleList;
}

<table id="contentTable" class="table table-hover table-bordered table-sm" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr class="table-light">
                <th style="width:10%">Delivery Date</th>
                <th style="width:10%">Hour</th>
                <th style="width:10%">Quantity</th>
                <th style="width:60%">Remarks</th>
                <th style="width:10%"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for (int i = 0; i < ScheduleList.Count; i++)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>@ScheduleList[i].split_date</td>
                <td>@ScheduleList[i].split_hour</td>
                <td>@ScheduleList[i].split_qty</td>
                <td>@ScheduleList[i].remarks</td>
                <td>
                    @Url.Action("Edit", "id", new RouteValueDictionary(new { Id = ScheduleList[i].Id }))
                </td>
            </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

It keeps giving me this error:

> CS0828: Cannot assign method group to anonymous type property

Is there anything wrong with my code?
Thank you very much in advance for any kind of help

Comment: `@Url.Action()` generates a url. Surely you want a link (using `@Html.ActionLink()`)? And are you wanting to navigate to the `Delete()` method and pass the `Id` of the `DeliverySchedule`?

Comment: @Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { Id= ScheduleList[i].Id })

Comment: yes i am, i want to navigate to `Delete()` while passing the `Id` of the selected `DeliverySchedule` in the table @StephenMuecke

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id= ScheduleList[i].Id })` assuming its in the same controller

Comment: What line of code is throwing that error?

Comment: Why in the world have you accepted that answer - its produces the identical result as your code

Comment: I just kinda realized that, I inputted a wrong controller name sorry @StephenMuecke

Comment: You do not even need to enter the controller name if its in the same controller. but that is irrelevant - the answer you have accepted has nothing what so ever to do with the error message you are getting (and why are your wanting the link to display `Edit` when the method is called `Delete`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try This

```
  <a href= '@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new RouteValueDictionary(new { Id = ScheduleList[i].Id }))'>Edit</a>
```

Comment: @Erick Vanhite try this. hopeful this will work for you

Comment: Please edit your answer to: `<a href= '@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new RouteValueDictionary(new { Id = ScheduleList[i].Id }))'>Edit</a>` As this is the code that worked for me